# Not So Unclad Riddle!

Tags: riddle, rhyme

> I could be brown or may be black, but, I ain't no snake.
>   I may bounce, though, not the ball.
>   Always tied, but, not the cuffs.
>   Not even the boots, but quite often tall.
>
> Call me a swine, I really don't care.
>   Both XX and XY may hold my possession.
>   I will lie back there, quietly as always.
>   Will cheer for the fact that I have my own equation!
>
> I have my home abaft the brain.
>   Oh I miss you, my Bruce and my Dwayne!

**Who am I?**

Comment: Thanks. (I deleted the comment you're thanking me for. Oops!)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**I thinks the desired answer is:**

> Ponytail

I could be brown or may be black, but, I ain't no snake.

> Brown or black colour of hairs & the snake is a refarance to shape of ponytails.

I may bounce, though, not the ball.

> Ponytails bounce with the movement of head.

Always tied, but, not the cuffs.

> Ponytails are nothing but bunch of hairs tied together.

Not even the boots, but quite often tall.

> Ponytails are quite long, some even tied in such a way that they looks like a shaft standing up before hairs falling down.

Call me a swine, I really don't care.

> Some people call ponytails, *pigtails* while both are diffarant.

Both XX and XY may hold my possession.

> Though ponytails are common in girls, even some mens also tie their hairs for style. *(XX and XY are referance to chromosomes which define gender of human baby.)*

I will lie back there, quietly as always.
Will cheer for the fact that I have my own equation!

> This seems like a refarance to [Ponytails Equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ponytail#Ponytail_equation)

I have my home abaft the brain.
Oh I miss you, my Bruce and my Dwayne!

> Hairs reside above brain on scalp. Last line is a referance to fact that both Bruce Willies and Dwayne Johnson dont have hairs on their heads!

### ---------------------------------------------------------------

**My first attempt was:**

> Hairs

---

I could be brown or may be black, but, I ain't no snake.

> Brown or black colour of hairs

I may bounce, though, not the ball.

> Hair bounces when you move, run, dance etc.

Always tied, but, not the cuffs.

> Tied at root to hair, or even in form of ponytails.

Not even the boots, but quite often tall.

> Hais can grow quite lengthy.

Call me a swine, I really don't care.

> Dont know exaclty but this might be a referance to unkept hair or a filthy person

Both XX and XY may hold my possession.

> Both genders posses hairs. XX and XY are referance to chromosomes which define gender of human baby.

I will lie back there, quietly as always.
Will cheer for the fact that I have my own equation!

> Little doibtful about this. Hairs are considered as style statement and attractive. Though they just sit on head people still take care of hairs and find them attractive.

I have my home abaft the brain.
Oh I miss you, my Bruce and my Dwayne!

> Hairs reside above brain on scalp. Last line is a referance to fact that both Bruce Willies and Dwayne Johnson dont have hairs on their heads!

Comment: You are quite close. +1

Comment: If 'not the ball' means like a bun - they do still bounce with a lot of movement. And 'always tied' implies hair is always tied, which is false.

Comment: @n_palum The right answer fits with everything :)

Comment: @Techidiot that's what I figured, since you said close I was pointing out things that may be considered why it isn't quite this thing.

Comment: Did you by any chance mean [a _theorem_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hairy_ball_theorem) as much as an equation, user @Techidiot?

Comment: ^ That's a nice find! Explains equation and the ball - but still leaves swine and maybe cuffs unexplained

Comment: @humn Nice find :) But no, I meant an actual equation and not theorem.

Comment: black-scholes? idk probably unrelated

Comment: Nice. You got it. And hence the riddle is not so unclad coz it has a pony tail :) +15

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer is

> DNA

Explanations

> Are bit obvious if I ain't wrong. The only thing that requires a bit more googling is Bruce, who is probably Bruce Lipton. And also there are numerous equations about DNA concentrations and all that.

Comment: Scarcely anything in the riddle seems to me to fit this well. Would you care to explain line by line?

Comment: While DNA may fit for the second paragraph I don't think it fits for the first one. You could argue Gender for the second paragraph. That DNA (XX/XY) decides it, it's in the brain, etc. And Bruce could be a reference to Bruce Jenner swapping genders so they miss them? But seems unlikely

Comment: What on Earth did user34872 do to get his (or her) account deleted within 20 minutes of posting this answer?

Comment: ^ Haha. Not sure what went wrong. But no, this is not the answer :)